# What organization sponsored 2022 Pacific Defense Chiefs meeting in Sydney, how many member nations does it have and which ones attended?

Tags: international-relations, military

The Diplomat's July 28, 2022 [Pacific Defense Chiefs Meet Against Backdrop of Rising China; Military leaders from 26 nations are participating in a conference hosted in Sydney.](https://thediplomat.com/2022/07/pacific-defense-chiefs-meet-against-backdrop-of-rising-china/) mentions how many nations participated in the actual meeting this year;

> Military leaders from **26** nations are participating in the conference, and most of those are chiefs of defense. China was invited but said it would be unable to attend.

though in ABC News (Australia)'s video [US General Mark Milley on the growing threat of China in the Pacific region](https://youtu.be/DlxoKXFvKAg?t=491) the US [Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Milley) gives a different total:

> I just came from a conference in Sydney, where **27** countries (from) Asia-Pacific were meeting to discuss common issues of national security.

and the U.S. Indo-Pacific Command (USINDOPACOM)'s July 27, 2022 news item [2022 Chiefs of Defense Conference Concludes](https://www.pacom.mil/Media/News/News-Article-View/Article/3108051/2022-chiefs-of-defense-conference-concludes/) includes a photograph with what appears to be **28** individuals wearing military uniforms.

**Question(s):**

1. What specific organization sponsored this 2022 Pacific Defense Chiefs meeting in Sydney?
2. How many member nations does it have? (numbers like 26, 27 and 28 seem possible)
3. Which members attended this conference?

---

[image: U.S. Indo-Pacific Command (USINDOPACOM)'s July 27, 2022 news item "2022 Chiefs of Defense Conference Concludes" https://www.pacom.mil/Media/News/News-Article-View/Article/3108051/2022-chiefs-of-defense-conference-concludes/]

Source: U.S. Indo-Pacific Command (USINDOPACOM)'s July 27, 2022 news item [2022 Chiefs of Defense Conference Concludes](https://www.pacom.mil/Media/News/News-Article-View/Article/3108051/2022-chiefs-of-defense-conference-concludes/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What specific organization sponsored this 2022 Pacific Defense Chiefs meeting in Sydney?**

The conference is co-hosted annually by US Indo-Pacific Command and the military of the host-country; in 2022 this was the Australian Defence Force.

**How many member nations does it have?**

It doesn't really have member nations - the Indo-Pacific Command's area of responsibility covers [36 nations](https://www.pacom.mil/About-USINDOPACOM/USPACOM-Area-of-Responsibility/), but not all of these have militaries such as Samoa, and some don't attend or aren't invited, for example China or North Korea. In addition, some countries outwith the region also send representation, for example the UK and Canada.

**Which members attended this conference?**

27 countries attended in 2022; the picture in the question shows the head of each country's delegation. There are two from the US - one representing the Indo-Pacific Command and one representing the US Armed Forces in general. From left to right, these are:

1. Air Marshal B. R. Krishna (India)
2. Lieutenant General Fap Igor Guzmán Sánchez (Peru)
3. Lieutenant General Melvyn Ong (Singapore)
4. Lieutenant General Phung Si Tan (Vietnam)
5. General Notaphol Bunngam (Thailand)
6. General Muhammad Andika Perkasa (Indonesia)
7. General Kōji Yamazaki (Japan)
8. Unknown (Cambodia)
9. Lieutenant General Park Jeong-hwan (South Korea)
10. Admiral John C. Aquilino (USA)
11. Vice Admiral Nicolas Vaujour (France)
12. Admiral Rob Bauer (Netherlands)
13. General Angus Campbell (Australia)
14. Brigadier General Lord Fielakepa (Tonga)
15. Admiral Sir Tony Radakin (UK)
16. General Mark Milley (USA)
17. Major General Jone Kalouniwai (Fiji)
18. Vice-Admiral Bob Auchterlonie (Canada)
19. Air Marshal Kevin Short (New Zealand)
20. Lieutenant General Waker-Uz-Zaman (Bangladesh)
21. Lieutenant General Falur Rate Laek (Timor-Leste)
22. General Andres Centino (Philippines)
23. General Prabhu Ram Sharma (Nepal)
24. Lieutenant General Dovchinsurengiin Ganzorig (Mongolia)
25. Commodore Philip Polewara (Papua New Guinea)
26. Unknown (Malaysia)
27. José Nogueira León (Chile)
28. Major General Dato Paduka Seri Haji Muhammad Haszaimi bin Bol Hassan (Brunei)

Comment: It would be good to reference some more sources. Did you recognise the people in the photo, or was there an official list (e.g. from the photo agency)?

Comment: @StuartF there's not an official list as far as I'm aware - bar the few mentioned in the news item linked in the OP. The majority I just recognised, and I recognise the uniform of the Malaysian and Cambodian members but not the individuals.